# Audio tag GUI not visible

Tags: html, audio, audiojs

I have included the audio tag on a page as

```
<audio src='a.mp3' preload='auto'>
</audio>
```

but its not working, i can't see anything on the page.

But when i include audiojs as

```
  <script src="/static/js/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    audiojs.events.ready(function() {
      var as = audiojs.createAll();
    });

  </script>
```

I am left wondering why is that so ?

Comment: I think you need to add the attributes 'controls' to see something

Comment: head on! controls is what i was missing thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

From what I've learned, src is an element inside audio, not an attribute. So your code should look like this:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

[(Source)](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp)

**Edit:** src can also be an attribute, so that wasn't your problem. In order for the browser to display *anything* for audio, you need the "controls" attribute. However, if you don't want the default controls, add html buttons and control the start/stop etc. of the audio with JavaScript.

Comment: The src attribute can be a URL of the audio file or the path to the file on the local system. [See Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox)

Comment: Fair enough, should have checked the reference. Cheers!

Comment: One more thing do not refer w3schools practices. Try to share [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh828809(v=vs.85).aspx) or [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=en) references. Thanks!

Comment: Even if you don't assign value to controls attribute still it'll work.

Answer (score 9):

Try This:

```
<audio src='a.mp3' controls preload='auto'>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your CSS.

```
    audio{
        min-width: 400px;
        height: auto;
        object-fit: inherit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping audio tag using figure. I also had the same problem. then I went to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

```html
<div id="app">
      <figure>
        <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
        <audio
          id="#audio"
          controls
          src="http://jPlayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3"
        >
          <a href="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"> Download audio </a>
        </audio>
      </figure>
    </div>
```