# <audio> tag not appearing in bootstrap table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using Bootstrap's table and i can't figure out why `<audio>` tag is not appearing inside the `<td>`

```
<td><audio src="mysrc.extension"></audio></td>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audio tag GUI not visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968309/audio-tag-gui-not-visible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your audio player is not displaying because your `<audio>....</audio>` tag is missing the `controls` attribute.

Try this:

```
<td><audio src="mysrc.extension" controls></audio></td>
```

---

**Q. Wait what is the `controls` attribute for??**

A. The `controls` attribute adds audio controls, like play, pause, and volume to the audio player.